# Paypal advanced GET fields returned

Tags: php, paypal

This is a very easy question.
I need to code a receipt for a paypal advanced payflow (the page at RETURNURL). Unfortunately, the site is live and I can't switch it to sandbox for testing and I don't want to use my money testing it... 
What I need to know :

- Are the COMMENT1 and COMMENT2 fields returned as part of the GET response on a successful transaction?
- Could someone send me a full GET request (anonymized) so I have all the fields and avoid asking more questions about the same thing?

Something like `success.php?RESP=xxx+NAME=xxx+...` would do just fine.

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: You don't have a dev environment to test with?  I'd recommend it, or you won't really be able to ever work on this part of your website again because it is live.

Comment: Use the Sandbox IPN....

Comment: The client has pushed to make it live, then has decided he wanted to change the success page. I have already done it a few times, I just need to know about COMMENT1 and 2. Of course I'd use sandbox if I could, read my question...